# Live Stream midroll ad injection in Wowza Streaming Engine

Tags: streaming, live, wowza

I haven't found any way to automate inserting an ad spot into an existing live stream without stopping the streams and/or using a Flash client to interact with Wowza.

The idea is that these ads can be randomly chosen and inserted into the stream programatically & automated.

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to properly change sources on the fly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following articles may be of interest for you

- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-switch-streams-using-stream-class-streams
- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-control-stream-class-streams-dynamically-modulestreamcontrol
- https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-use-ipublishingprovider-api-to-publish-server-side-live-streams

I've previously created a custom module for Wowza that allows you to create an output stream from a live input stream, then control the output and switch between the live input stream and other live or on demand streams.

Comment: Which approach of the above 3 did you use in your module? I am trying this with the IPublishingProvider API and getting annoying freezes which are short with RTMP and very long with HLS and complete freeze with MPEG-DASH..

Comment: I've used all of them in various modules; I've written a whole bunch of modules over the past years. It's not easy to tell the cause of your freezes without knowing the code and the purpose of your module.